# Adding in a python module to the sys.path for a Java project in pydev, Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import, pydev, sys.path

I've been following the Jython book to be able to get a Java application to import a Python module.

http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html#one-to-one-jython-object-factories specifically says **"In order to utilize a Jython module using this technique, you must either ensure that the .py module is contained within your sys.path, or hard code the path to the module within your Java code"**

How do I ensure that the .py module is added to the sys.path within pydev in Eclipse?. I'm using Eclipse Kepler release Build id: 20130614-0229, Pydev version 2.8.1 and JDK 6.

I keep getting import errors whenever I try to import a Python module.

Printing sys.path from the Java class as in the following snippet tells me that the sys.path is composed of ['C:\jython2.5.3\Lib', '**classpath**', '**pyclasspath**/'].

How do I set this sys.path in the project properties (or anywhere within the Pydev development environment)?

I do not want to modify sys.path in the Java code?

```
public BuildingFactory() {
    PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
    interpreter.exec("import sys");
    interpreter.exec("import sys.path");
    interpreter.exec("print sys.path");
    interpreter.exec("from Building import Building");
    buildingClass = interpreter.get("Building");
    }
```

['C:\jython2.5.3\Lib', '**classpath**', '**pyclasspath**/']
Exception in thread "main" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named Building

**UPDATE**

Per http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/InstallingJython#What_do_.22python.path.22_and_.22python.prepath.22_mean_in_the_Jython_registry.3F, the python.path was modified in the Jython registry file to add the Python module to the pythonpath. Thanks, @SimonC for the hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having spent a few seconds looking at the documentation (so I've no ide if this actually works), it looks like you can use pass in a [PySystemState](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/core/PySystemState.html) to the [PythonInterpreter](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html#PythonInterpreter%28org.python.core.PyObject,%20org.python.core.PySystemState%29) constructor.  The `PySystemState` has a public [path](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/core/PySystemState.html#path) field that (I assume) you can append path entries to.

UPDATE

As you want to specify the path in the runtime configuration, then it looks like you can do this by specifying the `python.path` system property on the command line (from the [Jython FAQ](http://www.jython.org/archive/22/userfaq.html#my-modules-can-not-be-found-when-imported-from-an-embedded-application)):

```
Properties props = new Properties();
// set in the VM args in the Eclipse runtime configuration instead
// props.setProperty("python.path", "/home/modules:scripts");
PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), props,
                             new String[] {""});
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to precisely avoid modification of the sys.path within the Java code, including use of PySystemState. Thanks for looking up the documentation, @SimonC.

Comment: Why?  At what level do you want to add your entries to the python path?  Do you want anything that runs on your machine to have the same path, or just a specific run configuration from within Eclipse?

Comment: To answer your question - a specific run configuration from within Eclipse. I'm using the pydev plugin. Ideally, for Eclipse Java Project A - I'd like to be able to modify the project properties to say that Project A use the python module pYM from Eclipse Project B, all projects are located in the same Eclipse workspace.

Comment: thanks for your persistence. Your answer with regards to modifying the python.path system property was close enough. The Jython FAQ hint was timely. It turns out that the python.path can be modified in the Jython registry file.

Answer (score 2):

For PyDev/Eclipse, you should mark your folder as a source folder (source folders are the folders in the project which will be added to the PYTHONPATH).

See http://pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html for details (and it has a section in the end if you want to point to a java project from within jython).

Comment: Thanks, @fabio-zadrozny. I have no problems in pointing to a java project from a jython project. My question concerns the other way round, i.e. pointing to a python project from a java project. The Python project folders are already marked as source folders. However, the Java project still does not see those Python project files on the sys.path. I also have a '__init__.py' in the Python source folders.

Comment: The Pydev plugin should allow for much more easier modification of the sys.path. This will benefit other Pydev users immensely as well. Please consider this as a humble request to improve the Pydev plugin. Not to discount the tremendous amount of work and effort and you and others have put into developing Pydev, it is truly appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I think I really misunderstood it... Well, for things the other way around, you have to add the folders where the .pyc$class are generated to JDT (so, it's more a matter of making JDT see the Jython classes -- in which case I don't really see how to fix things in the PyDev side...). Or maybe I'm still misunderstanding things here :)

Comment: Right @fabio-zadrozny, it concerns with the Java project seeing the .pyc$class - Jython classes. However the fundamental question is --- Cannot the sys.path within a Java project in PyDev be modified?